# Rasterize and get only pixels whose center falls within the feature's geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine, rasterization, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do I rasterize a feature collection to the scale and projection of a raster?

For my output I need only those pixels whose center falls within the feature geometry. Not pixels partially (<50%) intersecting with the feature's geometry.

This is the result I get:

[image]

My attempt (+ solution based on mandal_msh answer):

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// Test data ////////

// Create roi.
var roitest = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[32.87518562163141,34.93849391328985], 
  [32.87721337164667,34.93849391328985], 
  [32.87721337164667,34.939923112538985], 
  [32.87518562163141,34.939923112538985], 
  [32.87518562163141,34.93849391328985]]
]);

// Create polygon.
var polytest = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[32.87616194569716,34.93953744992619], 
  [32.87572742783675,34.93914606984455], 
  [32.87623704754958,34.93878986837149], 
  [32.87665010773787,34.93919884030158],
  [32.87616194569716,34.93953744992619]]
]);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// Get S2 Image Collection ////////

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");
var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

var maskS2clouds = function(image){
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

var preinput = s2.filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-06-30')
  .filterBounds(roitest).sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .map(maskS2clouds).first();

var input = ee.Image(preinput);

//Clip input to polygon borders
var raster = input.clip(roitest);

var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 1000,
  max: 2000,
  gamma: 2.0
};

//Plot image
Map.centerObject(roitest, 18)
Map.addLayer(raster, vizParams, 'raster');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// Rasterize polygon ////////

// Select band B2 from raster
var B2 = raster.select('B2');

// Get information about the B2 projection.
var B2Projection = B2.projection();

var poly = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(polytest).set('id', ee.Number(5))]);
print(poly);

// Make an image out of the id attribute to the scale and projection of B2.
var poly_ras = poly
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['id']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['id'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).reproject({crs: B2Projection}); 

var clipped_poly_ras = poly_ras.clip(poly);

Map.addLayer(poly_ras, {gamma: 2.0}, 'poly_ras');
Map.addLayer(poly, {color: 'red'}, 'poly');  
Map.addLayer(clipped_poly_ras , {gamma:1.0}, 'clipped_poly_ras');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clip the new raster by your feature, which will mask out the pixels outside the feature...

Comment: Thank you. I have validated that it is correct !